# How the horizontal menu was created in Customizr theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a horizontal menu using

```
display : inline
```

so I expected that Wordpress themes do the same. However, inspecting

http://demo.presscustomizr.com/

with Firefox Developer I have not found such a css rule. How is it achieved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use float: left to position the li elements horizontally.

Inspect a list element and you will see this:

```
.navbar .nav>li {
    float: left;
}
```